# java - how do you make one ArrayList for each subclass?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, arraylist

I am trying to make an ArrayList that can be used by all subclasses of one abstract class, but the object types should be of the sublcasses.

To make it simple, here's an example:

There is an abstract class called 'Animal', and there are three subclasses called 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Pig'.
So, I want to make an '`ArrayList<Animal> all`', and this list should be used by the subclasses to store the objects in their lists.
So, there must be an '`ArrayList<Dog>`', '`ArrayList<Cat>`' and '`ArrayList<Pig>`' and so on.
I don't want to loop through the 'Animal' class, then convert each object cause that will make the non-inherited methods and values inaccessible...

I wanna do this so I can iterate through the objects faster.

Comment: You need only one list , not others.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to create `Map<? extends Animal, List<? extends Animal>>` without Reflection (i.e., looking at runtime for each implementation of `Animal`)? Alternative is just to have a `List<Animal>` and rely on dynamic dispatching. I don't really understand your use-case though.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be more clear.

When you use `Dog.all` or `Cat.all` or `Pig.all`, this should return the ArrayList that contains all instances of the subclass. For example, if you call `Dog.all` it should return a `ArrayList<Dog>`.

I can do this by creating an ArrayList for each subclass with the name 'all', but in case when you have like 20 subclasses, repeating the same code would be a pain in the neck.... I'm looking for a more simple solution for this

Comment: For your abstraction to work, you should have all the behaviour (methods) you need to call be present in the parent class, but at run time, the call will be routed polymorphically to the subtypes, if you still need to cast each type to the subtype while looping, then you are breaking the abstraction

Answer (score 4):

To give each subtype a list of its type, make Animal generic.

In Animal.java:

```
public class Animal<AnimalType extends Animal> {
    public List<AnimalType> getAll() {
        return all;
    }
    private List<AnimalType> all = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In Dog.java:

```
public class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {
    public void doSomething() {
        for (Dog dog: getAll()) {
        }
    }
}
```

By making Animal "generic" you generally will want to refer to the specific type of animal you are dealing with. So, if you declare a variable to be of type Animal, you will want to include the type information (otherwise, you will get warnings about raw types). For example:

```
Animal<Dog> myFirstDog = ...;
```

If you want to refer to animals in general, then you might do this:

```
Animal<?> myFirstPet = ...;
```

If you make your animal hierarchy more interesting and also generic, then you might say something like:

```
Animal<? extends Canine> ...
```

which would might match Animal, Animal, or Animal.

In this last example:

In Canine.java:

```
public class Canine extends Animal<Canine> {
}
```

In Dog.java:

```
public class Dog extends Canine<Dog> {
}
```

In Coyote.java:

```
public class Coyote extends Canine<Coyote> {
}
```

Comment: I got a marker in Eclipse. It says "- Animal is a raw type. References to generic type Animal<Dog> should be parameterized.
- The public type Animal must be defined in its own file."

I don't understand these things much, can you explain a bit more? Thx.

Comment: @Robby I have edited to add more detail and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Generics. For example:

```
class Animal<T> {
    List<T> all
}

class Cat extends Animal<Cat> {...}
```

I'm not sure about your needs in extends and super keywords here. In my sample list of cats can contain only cats, not other animals or subclasses of Cat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rewriting the answer as per your comments. You said

> I guess I haven't explained well. I don't need an ArrayList for each instance of the subclasses, I need an ArrayList for each subclass (which means it will be protected static). However, I can't initialize it in the super class because I have to type 'ArrayList', while I need ArrayList and ArrayList

You want a global list, where you would store all your animals. Again I don't see a point in you having the list in your class hierarchy, let alone a protected static one. This means that all the subclasses are sharing the same list - which means it's impossible to implement it like you want to.

Why not extract the lists into a repository and then store the animals there? You can always filter them into a new list of animals you need here:

```
public class CrazyAnimalRepositry {

    private List<CrazyAnimal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T extends CrazyAnimal> List<T> filterForAnimalType(Class<T> filteringClass){
        return animals.stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getClass().equals(filteringClass))
                .map(t -> (T) t)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void addAnimal(CrazyAnimal animal){
        animals.add(animal);
    }
}
```

You can use this repository as follows:

```
public void testAnimals(){
    CrazyAnimalRepositry repositry = new CrazyAnimalRepositry();

    Dog dog = new Dog();
    Cat myCatz = new Cat();

    repositry.addAnimal(dog);
    repositry.addAnimal(myCatz);


    for(Cat cat : repositry.filterForAnimalType(Cat.class)){
        cat.meow();
    }
}
```

You can also put the repository within your base class Crazy Animal, and have access to the same object from there. from there you can filter the list by calling **filterForanimalType** and passing in the class you are at.

Comment: I guess I haven't explained well.
I don't need an ArrayList for each instance of the subclasses, I need an ArrayList for each subclass (which means it will be protected static).
However, I can't initialize it in the super class because I have to type '`ArrayList<Animal>`', while I need `ArrayList<Dog>` and `ArrayList<Cat>`

Comment: Don't do that. That's global state, and it's not the way to go.
Rather keep the list somewhere in a separate object. E.g. an animal Repository.

The way you are thinking, it's not just how java works. When you make it protected and static, all your subclasses will be sharing the list. You can make a generic Repository which can filter by type of subclass and return the subList you need to work with.